# How to pass the authorization in ajax CORS request in Firebug?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

I am trying to making an admin request to a server that is hosted on https through ajax jquery.  Somehow the header authentication parameters are not getting passed in the request and I get a 401 error . 
    I am not able to pass the header authorization information and  I am getting 401 unauthorized error .  How do I pass the authorization in the  header? 
    Any body faced this issue before , any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Below is my ajax request ::::

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
         xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=");
         xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
         xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
         xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type");
         } ,
    url: '/test.html',
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "json", 
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
        },
    contentType: "application/json" , 
    data: {
        'name'    : 'test123456',
        'description'   : 'test' ,
        'owner'   : 'admin' ,
        'accessRestriction'   : 'VIEW' 
        },
    cache : true, 
     success : function(service_data) {
         alert("success");
      },
     error : function(msg) {
         alert("error");
       }
 });
```

Comment: Ajax requests are usually limited to the same domain, port and  protocol— https could be the issue. The request needs to also come from https.

Comment: well, did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing `content-type` in the allow headers, need to pass the Authorization as well.